# How can I copy text from span to a data-group attribute without IDs?

Tags: javascript, html

I to need extract text from  tags, which are under every image I have on my website. My goal is to make a link with same URL as images has. This is not issue, this already working. Problem is that I need the value of the `data-group` attribute from the span tag inside this link, for every picture inside grid, so in case I have two pictures next to each other, they will have same data-group name from common span tag.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.two_pics div img').each(function() {
    var $img = $(this);

    <!-- var test = $(this).parent().parent().children(':first').children().children(); -->
    <!-- var one = two.getElementsByTagName("span")[0]; -->
    <!-- var a = document.getElementsByClassName("two_pics"); -->
    <!-- a.getElementsByTagName("span"); -->
    var list = document.getElementsByClassName("two_pics")[0];
    var test = document.getElementsByTagName("span")[0];
    console.log(test.innerText);
    <!-- console.log($one.textContent); -->
    $img.wrap('<a href="' + $img.attr('src') + '" class="lightbox" data-group="' + test.innerText + '"></a>');

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div_grid" id="myUL">
  <div style="order:1" class="two_pics">
    <div><a><span>KZO3</span></a></div>
    <div><img src="sucast_kroja/315.jpg"></div>
    <div><img src="sucast_kroja/316.jpg"></div>
  </div>
  <div style="order:2" class="two_pics">
    <div><a><span>KZO4</a></div>
    <div><img src="sucast_kroja/398.png" data-group="398"></div>
    <div><img src="sucast_kroja/397.png" data-group="398"></div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this simpler script using closest to get the text

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.two_pics div img').each(function() {
    const $img = $(this);
    const text = $img.closest(".two_pics").find("div span").text()
    $img.wrap(`<a href="${$img.attr('src')}" class="lightbox" data-group="${text}"></a>`);
    
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div_grid" id="myUL">
  <div style="order:1" class="two_pics">
    <div><a><span>KZO3</span></a></div>
    <div><img src="sucast_kroja/315.jpg"></div>
    <div><img src="sucast_kroja/316.jpg"></div>
  </div>
  <div style="order:2" class="two_pics">
    <div><a><span>KZO4</a></div>
    <div><img src="sucast_kroja/398.png" data-group="398"></div>
    <div><img src="sucast_kroja/397.png" data-group="398"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Many thx, this works great :) i learned something new.